# get the text from the text area in the same manner as has been formatted there

Tags: java, servlets

There is a properly formatted text in Html `textarea` which looks like :

[image]

As this *song/poem* is submitted a servlet handles it and and puts it all in the string and saves it in the servlet context.At one point I have to display the poem submitted but when I get that attribute from the servlet context it displays the text *in one single line*.

What should I do to save the text as String in the servlet context that is formatted in the same manner as has been formatted in the text area.

*servlet snippet that handles the poem :*

```
    String poetry = request.getParameter("poetry");
   String poet = request.getParameter("poet");

   ServletContext context = getServletContext();

   poetryMapsPoet = (HashMap<String,String>)context.getAttribute("Poetry");

   if(poetryMapsPoet == null) {
       poetryMapsPoet = new HashMap<String,String>();
       context.setAttribute("Poetry", poetryMapsPoet);
   }
   poetryMapsPoet.put(poetry, poet);
   // Poetry is the key and poet is the value
```

Comment: +1 for the beautiful poem. will read question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in a pre block:

```
<pre><c:out value="${thePoem}"/></pre>
```

Or use a tag that will transform every end of line into a `<br/>`. I've always wondered why this wasn't part of the JSTL. But it's pretty easy to write yourself.

Comment: how do i detect the end of line ? I get it like this `String poetry = request.getParameter("poetry");` How can I detect line breaks in a string ?

Comment: Use a BufferedReader around a StringReader, for example, and read line by line, appending a `<br/>` at the end of every line.

Comment: but how do I start reading before the text is submitted to the servlet ? If it is submitted it will be a normal string

Comment: You get the text of the poem from the request parameter, coming from the form submission. You store it somewhere. Later, you want to display this poem in another HTML page. So you transform the text by adding <br/> at the end of each line, and output this transformed text to the HTTP response.

Comment: it worked . I wrote this : `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(poetry_st));
           while(br.read() > 0) {
               poetry  += br.readLine() + "<br />"; 
           }` I was thinking that `poetry_st` is a string with no line breaks. _( String poetry_st = request.getParameter("poetry"); )_